# Intuitive relationship between convexity, rank, and positive (semi) definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I understand PD implies full rank and strict convexity and PSD implies convexity, but I am not quite sure how this works, and what I can infer about rank if I know a matrix is PSD.

Comment: If a matrix is PSD, all we know regarding rank is that it isn’t full rank.

Comment: Well, positive semi definite includes positiv definite.

Comment: The matrices $0,I$ are positive semi definite and have quite different rank. You cannot infer anything about rank on the basis of semi definiteness alone.

Comment: Right, so a PSD matrix (Hessian, in this case) could have full rank (if it's also PD) or not (in which case the function is still convex but no guarantee about it being strictly convex)?